# Dual Grounding Electrodes In Parallel versus series

Tags: electrical, grounding

I've installed two 8' copper rods each with a beefy copper wire tying them back to the panel ground.  It is the entrance panel, so neutral is also on that ground and the service pole is ~15' away with its own ground rod I'd assume.  I've seen most everyone else put their rods in series, but I ran two wires for mine.  I'm not sure it matters but it did allow me to answer this question:
"**what is the impedance between two 8' copper grounding rods installed 10' apart for my soil**".
While this will give insight into the soil path resistance, it is not equivalent to the NEC required measurement of <25ohms for a single ground rod to earth.  Taking this measurement requires special equipment to emulate the earth connection.

[image]

Comment: #2 ground wire is very  large for grounding. Usually #6 is fine, some places might require #4. And frankly, your setup with independent grounding conductors is superior to "series".

Comment: Yes, I interrupted NEC wrong and believed i needed #2 for a 400A service. still predicting ive got better than 20ohms between them because copper to dirt and through dirt is a terrible electrical path

Comment: Driven rods only require a 6 awg unless connecting to a ufer ground then #4 is required. You don’t measure between them, buried rods are fine but they do not work as well in the summer, your inspector may flag that if not required due to rock. You don’t have a ufer ground? Concrete encased electrode these are the best. I have seen parallel but is is a lot of extra copper and doesn’t improve the grounding.  It takes a special meter to measure earth resistance, your actual resistance may be 2x be prepared to be disappointed, since I have the meter I measure and rarely 25 ohms with 2 driven

Comment: If the ground wire is run down in a trench, it adds to the effective electrode. If 36" or more down, it even counts, I believe.

Comment: I don't get why somebody DV'd this post? It sounds like an intelligent and thoughtful question. Would whoever DV'd the OP please say why?

Comment: This is just a simple comment regard ufer grounds. I was wondering what ufer stood for, possibly an acronym.  Turns out that it's Herbert G. Ufer, a consultant working for the Army in 1942 that discovered and developed the concrete encased grounding system.

Comment: @ecnerwal yes the copper in the trench adds to the effective grounding and #2 or larger wire is required for loops. George there are a few that downvote excellent questions with no explanation my only guess is because the question refers to doing something that would be non code compliant. Or thier own lack of knowledge. So I reverse these all the time. Yep on ufer it is by far the best (other than a metal well shaft).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP explicitly states that there isn't a question here.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson because the OP explicitly states that he's _not_ asking a question! "Sharing science" is nice, but that's not what this site is for. Take it to chat or maybe meta.

Comment: @FreeMan  Agreed.  He should have asked and answered his question, clearly he knows what he's doing.+++++

Comment: valid point, @GeorgeAnderson. The OP _should_ rewrite this as a _question_, then write up an _answer_. Writing questions intending to self-answer it perfectly acceptable around here. However, writing a question that explicitly states `There is not really a question here unless I've missed something in the code regarding grounding rods, just an opportunity to share some "Science"` is expressly off-topic on a _Question & Answer_ forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had my trench inspection today and was able to burry the rods. After compacting the dirt the impedance between the two rods **measured 175 ohms**.  The distance between the vertical rod and the start of the horizontal rod at 36" depth was 10'.  Also, the bare copper wires in dirt passed within a foot of each other (this was likely a driver for the "low" measurement).  If I'm able to get a hold of the special equipment to measure each rods impedance to earth, I will add that  for "science".
As with most placing earth grounding rods, its easier to just ram two or more copper rods than go through the measurement per NEC. (Though a UFER ground would have been ideal if i'd thought that far ahead before I dumped 40 cubic Yards of Concrete down)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything that says you can't have it the way that you do. As long as each physical service has at least one ground of its own I think you're fine. Isolated ground systems aren't uncommon these days in residential dwellings, and that's how you'd do it (except you'd shield it and land it to an isolated ground bar in the can).

I've built large ground *rings* to deal with lightning which were always in series (#2 tin coat copper Cad Welded to 6 - 8 rods together about 10' apart, depending on the soil), but that was because we had to get extremely low resistance. The service grounds were completely separate. These are mandatory at cellular tower sites.

So with your setup, you just have options. Ever get any equipment that is *particularly* sensitive to noise? It would not be hard to set up an isolated ground bar and some IG receptacles. Or, just have fun measuring :)

Answer (score 1):

What NEC requires is you have 25 ohms on ground rod to earth, but if you can't meet the requirement you are required to install a second ground rod base 6 feet apart. The NEC requires that the ground in electrical electrode conductor to be not smaller then a number six AWG. You can elect to size the grounding electrode bigger, it just can't be samller then number 6 and you can connect the two ground rods in series.
As for an isolated system the isolated ground conductor will originate where the main bonding jumper or in a transformer main bonding jumper is located.